# pandas - searching for a character in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame (`df`) that I need to search for a semicolon. I first tried with

`semicolon_check = df.to_string().__contains__(';')`,

but it is very slow and in case of large DataFrames I run into a Memory error. Then I tried to loop over columns with `.str`, but not all columns are strings so whenever I reached a numeric column I received an error

`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

so I ended up with this code

`for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == 'O':
        if df[col].str.contains(r';').any():
            print 'found in ' + col`

is there an easier way to achieve the goal? The above, although working as expected seems like a bit too much of an effort for such an elementary task like value search.

Comment: This may not be the most efficient way but it loops safely: `df.applymap(lambda x: ";" in str(x))`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can filter just strings columns using [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) and then call `apply` and pass a `lambda` to call [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
In [33]:
# create a test df
df = pd.DataFrame({'int':np.arange(5), 'str':['a','a;a',';','b','c'], 'flt':np.random.randn(5), 'other str':list('abcde')})
df

Out[33]:
        flt  int other str  str
0  1.020561    0         a    a
1  0.022842    1         b  a;a
2 -1.207961    2         c    ;
3  1.092960    3         d    b
4 -1.560300    4         e    c

In [35]:
# filter on dtype
test = df.select_dtypes([np.object]).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(';').any())
test

Out[35]:
other str    False
str           True
dtype: bool
```

We can use the columns array from the filtered df along with the mask to filter the cols:

```
In [36]:
# we can use the above to mask the columns
str_cols = df.select_dtypes([np.object]).columns
str_cols[test]

Out[36]:
Index(['str'], dtype='object')
```